# Looking under the hood of DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Is it possible to print out information about the algorithms DSolve uses to solve a differential equation?

I'm looking for something similiar to [this](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=userinfo&term=infolevel) Maple procedure. It lets you specify how much information you want and in the case of dsolve prints out the different methods Maple uses to tackle the problem.

Since I'm currently using both programs, it would be interesting to compare how the approaches differ and why they sometimes produce different results.

Comment: Currently there doesn't seem to be any support for something like this; have a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WhyYouDoNotUsuallyNeedToKnowAboutInternals.html) for some justification.